# How to pass delegate parameter of .net dll in PowerBuilder 12.5

Tags: c#, powerbuilder

I am making a PowerBuilder Program. This program is using C# .net library file(.dll). But, I don't know how to pass callback function for event notifying in PowerBuilder application.

PowerBuilder
[image]

C# .net library file
[image]

I want to call SetConnectionInformation function in PowerBuilder in above images.
But, I don't know how to pass function.
Simply. I want to register function of PowerBuilder for calling in .net library(.dll).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass a function as parameter in PowerBuilder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53531446/how-to-pass-a-function-as-parameter-in-powerbuilder)

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53531446/how-to-pass-a-function-as-parameter-in-powerbuilder asked by OP