# How to pass a function as parameter in PowerBuilder

Tags: powerbuilder

Lately, I am using PowerBuilder 12.5 for application development.
But, I don't know how to pass a function as parameter in PowerBuilder. Is it possible? and what is the Callback type of Win API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PowerBuilder does not support callbacks or passing of functions as parameters.